# How do I generate a vector from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantitative-finance

Below is a screenshot of a `csv` file. I want to generate a vector of  growth rates by using pandas.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjSwg.png)

The growth rate is defined as `log(this year/previous year)` in my case.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This isn't a place to ask for people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
YearCode = np.arange(1970, 1975)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3),  columns = ['VariableCode', 'Region', 'AggValue'])
df['YearCode'] = YearCode
shifted = df['YearCode'].shift(1)
df['logValue'] = df['YearCode']/shifted
df['logValue'] = np.log(df['logValue'])
print(df)
   VariableCode    Region  AggValue  YearCode  logValue
0      0.374540  0.950714  0.731994      1970       NaN
1      0.598658  0.156019  0.155995      1971  0.000507
2      0.058084  0.866176  0.601115      1972  0.000507
3      0.708073  0.020584  0.969910      1973  0.000507
4      0.832443  0.212339  0.181825      1974  0.000507
```

**How it Works:**

Essentially you shift the 'YearCode' by 1 and divide the original column by the shifted one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I kinda understand how to did it. Sorry for the question format, I just regesiter this webist one day ago, and I will edit it. One more question, sorry for the blur question, my question is to get log(AggValue1971/AggValue1970), and I ran your code, it shows logValue 0.0005. But I use calculator the value is 0.02 which make sense. Could you please tell me how to get 0.02 in this question. The formula should be log(AggValue of 1971/AggValue of 1970) which is log(459102.34375/437890.15625). Cause I have captical stock to calculate. Thank you again! Much appreciated

Comment: `np.log` is the natural log by default. Change to `np.log10` if you want that. If you want to do it on the `AggValue`, the procedure is the same. Only make sure that your dataframe is sorted with respect to the `YearCode` column.